# How to serve any file type with Python's BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, httpserver

Consider the following example:

```
import string,cgi,time
from os import curdir, sep
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        try:
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                f = open(curdir + sep + self.path) #self.path has /test.html
#note that this potentially makes every file on your computer readable by the internet

                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type',    'text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
                return

        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)


def main():
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', 80), MyHandler)
        print 'started httpserver...'
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '^C received, shutting down server'
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What if I want to server a ZIP file also... how would I do that?
I don't think this line would work right?

```
self.wfile.write(f.read())
```

Comment: Can someone explain why the call to open() "potentially makes every file on your computer readable"?  And how would you protect against this for serving files in this example?

Comment: @brooksbp I think he means that the user could type a path that would navigate into another directory on your computer, for example going up one or more directories. But only html files could be accessed using the above code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass binary as a parameter to open(). This:

```
f = open(curdir + sep + self.path, 'rb')
```

Instead of this:

```
f = open(curdir + sep + self.path)
```

UNIX doesn't distinguish between binary and text, but windows does. But if the script executes on UNIX, the "b" will just be ignored so you're safe.

Comment: And in Python 3, Python makes a difference between binary and text files, so you might as well put the correct flag there already now. :)

Answer (score 4):

Your line would work just fine.  The problem would be setting the `Content-type` appropriately.  You'd want to set it to `application/zip` instead of `text/html`.

Comment: that's true, but i had already done that.
JosefAssad identified the problem i was having.  But you're correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to share files in a folder of any type, then you can also try typing the command

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

This will start the server at port 8000 and you can browse the files (via directory listing)