# Python33 - Improving server security with BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, file, security, http, webserver

I have lately been improving security on my webserver, which I wrote myself using `http.server` and `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`. I have blocked (`403`'d) most essential server files, which I do not want users to be able to access. Files include the python server script and all databases, plus some HTML templates.

However, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094185/how-to-serve-any-file-type-with-pythons-basehttprequesthandler) post on stackoverflow I read that using `open(curdir + sep + self.path)` in a do_GET request might potentially make every file on your computer readable. 
Can someone explain this to me? If the `self.path` is `ip:port/index.html` every time, how can someone access files that are above the root `/` directory?

I understand that the user (obviously) can change the `index.html` to anything else, but I don't see how they can access directories above `root`.

Also if you're wondering why I'm not using `nginx` or `apache`, I wanted to create my own web server and website for learning purposes. I have no intention to run an actual website myself, and if I do want to, I will probably rent a server or use existing server software.

```
class Handler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):

        try:
            if "SOME BLOCKED FILE OR DIRECTORY" in self.path:
                self.send_error(403, "FORBIDDEN")
                return
            #I have about 6 more of these 403 parts, but I left them out for readability
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                if self.path.endswith("index.html"):
                    #template is the Template Engine that I created to create dynamic HTML content
                    parser = template.TemplateEngine()
                    content = parser.get_content("index", False, "None", False)
                    self.send_response(200)
                    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(content.encode("utf-8"))
                    return
                elif self.path.endswith("auth.html"):
                    parser = template.TemplateEngine()
                    content = parser.get_content("auth", False, "None", False)
                    self.send_response(200)
                    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(content.encode("utf-8"))
                    return
                elif self.path.endswith("about.html"):
                    parser = template.TemplateEngine()
                    content = parser.get_content("about", False, "None", False)
                    self.send_response(200)
                    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(content.encode("utf-8"))
                    return
                else:
                    try:
                        f = open(curdir + sep + self.path, "rb")
                        self.send_response(200)
                        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
                        self.end_headers()
                        self.wfile.write((f.read()))
                        f.close()
                        return
                    except IOError as e:
                        self.send_response(404)
                        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
                        self.end_headers()
                        return
            else:
                if self.path.endswith(".css"):
                    h1 = "Content-type" 
                    h2 = "text/css"
                elif self.path.endswith(".gif"):
                    h1 = "Content-type"
                    h2 = "gif"
                elif self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
                    h1 = "Content-type"
                    h2 = "jpg"
                elif self.path.endswith(".png"):
                    h1 = "Content-type"
                    h2 = "png"
                elif self.path.endswith(".ico"):
                    h1 = "Content-type"
                    h2 = "ico"
                elif self.path.endswith(".py"):
                    h1 = "Content-type"
                    h2 = "text/py"
                elif self.path.endswith(".js"):
                    h1 = "Content-type"
                    h2 = "application/javascript"
                else:
                    h1 = "Content-type"
                    h2 = "text"
                f = open(curdir+ sep + self.path, "rb")
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header(h1, h2)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
                return
        except IOError:
            if "html_form_action.asp" in self.path:
                pass
            else:
                self.send_error(404, "File not found: %s" % self.path)
        except Exception as e:
            self.send_error(500)
            print("Unknown exception in do_GET: %s" % e)
```

Comment: Without your current code, it's a little hard to point out any exploitable flaws.

Comment: @Blender I updated the OP with the core part of my `do_GET` function in `Handler`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making an invalid assumption:

> If the `self.path` is `ip:port/index.html` every time, how can someone access files that are above the root / directory?

But `self.path` is *never* `ip:port/index.html`. Try logging it and see what you get.

For example, if I request `http://example.com:8080/foo/bar/index.html`, the `self.path` is not `example.com:8080/foo/bar/index.html`, but just `/foo/bar/index.html`. In fact, your code couldn't possibly work otherwise, because `curdir+ sep + self.path` would give you a path starting with `./example.com:8080/`, which won't exist.

And then ask yourself what happens if it's `/../../../../../../../etc/passwd`.

This is one of many reasons to use `os.path` instead of string manipulation for paths. For examples, instead of this:

```
f = open(curdir + sep + self.path, "rb")
```

Do this:

```
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(curdir, self.path))
if os.path.commonprefix((path, curdir)) != curdir:
    # illegal!
```

I'm assuming that `curdir` here is an absolute path, not just `from os import curdir` or some other thing that's more likely to give you `.` than anything else. If it's the latter, make sure to `abspath` it as well.

This can catch other ways of escaping the jail as well as passing in `..` strings… but it's not going to catch everything. For example, if there's a symlink pointing out of the jail, there's no way `abspath` can tell that someone's gone through the symlink.

Comment: Yes, I got to the point of logging self.path, which always gave paths like `.\/index.html`. I am trying to make sense of the lines of code you gave me, and I don't fully understand how this is supposed to work. You first set the path, in my case `.\/index.html` and compare it to `C:\index.html`? Or is this supposed to work only on a server which is not portable, meaning you have to set all paths if you want to move your server to another directory.

Comment: @IPDGino: I don't even understand your question. Where am I comparing anything to `C:\index.html`? Unless `C:/` is your server root… in which case you're already giving full access to your entire hard drive, so what are you even worried about? Meanwhile, what do you mean "work only on a server which is not portable"? It is exactly as portable as your original code. I don't know what paths you're talking about setting; there's just the one, `curdir`, and you set that the same way you already are (which you haven't shown us).

Comment: I am not setting curdir anywhere. the line `curdir + sep + self.path` will give something like `./\index.html`. For me, the code you gave me will check if `./\somepath.file` is not `c:\somepath.file` and print `illegal`. This will always print illegal in my case, because I do not have the server files in the root of my harddrive.

Comment: Sorry I did not read your answer thoroughly. Curdir in my case is not an absolute path, because I want to make this application without having to set paths. But if this really is very unsafe, I might make an installer or that you can set the path yourself in a seperate config file.

Comment: @IPDGino: I'm not saying to hardcode an absolute path into your app for `curdir`—but you can _convert_ `curdir` into an absolute path. My answer explicitly says that if `curdir` is anything other than an absolute path, "make sure to `abspath` it as well". If you do that, it will work. (Also, I don't know why you think it's checking that `./\somepath.file` is `c:\somepath.file`. What it's checking is that the common prefix between the requested path and the root path curdir is the root path—in other words, that the requested path is somewhere underneath the root path.

Comment: @IPDGino: Also, even if you want your app to use the CWD at launch time as the web root, you should probably do something like `rootdir = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)` at the start, instead of `rootdir = os.curdir`. That means you won't be affected by a later `chdir`, you can log useful paths to the logs, you can check files against your root without having to `abspath` over and over, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`self.path` contains the request path. If I were to send a `GET` request and ask for the resource located at `/../../../../../../../etc/passwd`, I would break out of your application's current folder and be able to access any file on your filesystem (that you have permission to read).

Comment: hmm. I think this only works on Linux or I am missing something. The `/` root folder I mentioned in the OP was the root directory of my server directory, not the linux root folder. And I tried a few things like entering `/../../../image.jpg` (A directory where I had put an image) and it did not work, just return me a `404` error.

Comment: after googling a bit, I found that on windows you use `..\ ` for a dds attack, but after trying a few times it did not work.

Comment: @IPDGino: Works just fine for me on Windows. You have to manually send the HTTP request. Typing it into a browser URL bar won't work.